# How to create custom InlineSpans in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I reuse pieces of code of `InlineSpan` type (e.g. `TextSpan`, `WidgetSpan`).

For example,

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      WidgetSpan(...), // code I like to reuse
      ... // other stuff
    ],
  ),
)
```

Of course I can write a function, that gives me this InlineSpan, like this:

```
InlineSpan myCustomWidgetSpan() {
  return WidgetSpan(...);
}
```

This is technically ok, but usually I reuse parts of code by creating a class that extends some other Flutter class (like `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`).

I think that there should be some more idiomatic approach to this. So what are the best practices for reusing code that produces `InlineSpan`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/span_builder

code snippet

```
final spans = SpanBuilder("The quick brown fox")
      .apply(TextSpan(text: "brown", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
      .apply(TextSpan(text: ""), whereText: "fox")
      .build();


Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: spans
              ),
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:span_builder/span_builder.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final spans = SpanBuilder("The quick brown fox")
      .apply(TextSpan(text: "brown", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
      .apply(TextSpan(text: ""), whereText: "fox")
      .build();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {     
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(         
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: spans
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compose InlineSpans by extending them and calling their super constructor.

```dart
class _MyWidgetSpan extends WidgetSpan {
  const _MyWidgetSpan({
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(
    // The stuff you want to reuse, say a text color.
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
    child: child,
  );
}
```